# Promise и foreach

Tags: javascript

Вопрос: практикуюсь в *JavaScript* по одноименной книжке, решил написать запрос на ресурс через `Promises`, однако они возвращают `undefined`. В чем может быть проблема? Заранее спасибо за ответы.

```
function requestAuthor(type) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open("GET", "http://eloquentjavascript.net/author", true);
    req.setRequestHeader("accept", type);
    req.addEventListener("load", function() {
        if (req.status < 400) {
            var responce = req.responceText;
            resolve(responce);
        }
        else 
            reject(error);

    });     
    req.send(null);
  });
}

var types = ["text/plain",
             "text/html",
             "application/json",
             "application/rainbows+unicorns"];

types.forEach(function(type) {

    requestAuthor(type)
        .then(function(resultOfRequest) {
            console.log(type + ":" + "\n" + resultOfRequest + "\n");
        })
            .catch(function(error){
                console.error(error);
            })
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Исправьте

```
var responce = req.responceText;
```

на

```
var responce = req.responseText;
```

(respon**s**eText вместо respon**c**eText)

Comment: добавлю что надо все таки на onreadystatechange вешаться а не load если надо еррорбэки тоже обрабатывать